# Mule PlaceHolder Documentation is wrong?

Tags: java, spring, deployment, mule, placeholder

i was looking to use the right way of the properties to deploy in multiple environments... but the example doesn't work:
URL: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/deploying-to-multiple-environments

**I created a project with an http configured as it appears in the example:**

```
<http:listener-config name="HttpListenerConfiguration"
                    doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"
                    host="${mule.env.host}"
                    port="${mule.env.port}"
                    basePath="${mule.env.basePath}" />
```

Where they say

> This example uses Spring’s property placeholder resolution mechanism. The variable bits are clearly visible: the base path, host, and port can vary for each environment where this connector gets deployed in. When deploying your application, mule.env can be dynamically replaced by the particular environment you’re deploying to, such as qa or prod.

**I created a file in java/main/resources called config.properties:**

```
dev.basePath=test/products
dev.host=localhost
dev.port=8082
prod.basePath=products
prod.host=www.acme.com
prod.port=8081
```

**and setup a place holder:**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="config.properties"/>
```

**my mule-app.properties:**

```
mule.env=dev
```

When i run it in AS:

```
[Could not resolve placeholder 'mule.env.host' in string value "<http:listener-config name="ejemplop....]
```

if i change the value from:

```
 ${mule.env.host} to ${${mule.env}.host}
```

and the host attribute works, but if i do the same with the port

```
(${${mule.env}.port}
```

give me an error

```
[..${${mule.env}.port}' is not a valid value of union type 'substitutableInt'....]
```

**but if i add in my properties file**

```
env.port=${${mule.env}.port}
```

and change the connector to:

```
<http:listener-config name="HttpListenerConfiguration"
                    doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"
                    host="${${mule.env}.host}"
                    port="${env.port}"
                    basePath="${mule.env.basePath}" />
```

it's works.
There is a fancy or proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

CHo, you are heading in the multiple environment direction, but not quite there yet.  What I would suggest if that you need multiple properties files, each of which have the same properties with the same names but environment specific values.

In your application, your would have something like:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="config_${mule.env}.properties"/>
```

Then in your flow you would have:

```
<http:listener-config name="HttpListenerConfiguration"
                    doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"
                    host="${host}"
                    port="${port}"
                    basePath="${basePath}" />
```

You would then have a property file named config_dev.properties and in it you would have:

```
basePath=test/products
host=localhost
port=8082
```

You would have another property file named config_prod.properties with:

```
basePath=products
host=www.acme.com
port=8081
```

When mule.env is set to dev, the config_dev values will be used.  When set to prod, the config_prod values are used.

Comment: Ty very much, this is how im using it right now in other proyects.
My mistake was thinking that "spring or Mule" will replace in ${mule.env.host} only the "${mule.env" part

Comment: @CHo  No problem.  The issue with how you were trying is that would take multiple passes to decode, and likely different syntax to tell the VM what order to do things in.  Even the method which does work takes multiple passes, but is simple enough logic that the Interpreter can decode it and do the placeholder substitution first as opposed to the nested substitutions you were attempting.  One thing to keep in mind as you attack such issues, mule vs. spring:  Mule is built on spring. There may be some slight syntax differences with mule, but it is implementing spring contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can ignore the mention of Spring for practical purposes. Under the covers, I think the global placeholder uses that technology. Here are simple steps that work for me:

1. In the mule-project.xml, create a mule.env variable having a value or either dev or qa, for example.
   [image: mule-project-xml variable]
2. Select your project xml, go to the Global Elements tab, and create a global property placeholder.

[image: global placeholder element]

3. Set the location to:

   ${mule.env}.properties
4. Create a qa.properties file in /src/main/app and define properties:

   mule.env.host=localhost

   mule.env.port=8082
5. Create a dev.properties file in src/main/app and define properties:

   mule.env.host=localhost

   mule.env.port=8081
6. In the HTTP listener configuration, set the host and port as follows:

   ${mule.env.host}

   ${mule.env.port}

When you run the app using the qa environment variable from step 1, you start the app from port 8081. Change the environment variable to dev and redeploy the app. Now you start the app from port 8082.

Here's the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd">
    <context:property-placeholder location="${mule.env}.properties"/>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="${mule.env.host}" port="${mule.env.port}" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <flow name="myprojectFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/users" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: Ty very much, this is how im using it right now in other proyects.
My mistake was thinking that "spring or Mule" will replace in ${mule.env.host} only the "${mule.env" part